# Como direccionar a una página

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
else {
  alert("No existen rutas entre ambos puntos");
  window.location="cotizacion.php";
}
```

El cual me manda una alerta. Lo que pretendo es que después que se muestre la alerta me mande a la página de cotización pero no lo hace. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa luego de aceptar? ¿Ves algún error en consola?

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que estes en un `iframe`, intenta con `top.window.location="cotizacion.php"`

Comment: el else si funciona pero ya intente con window.location.href y con el top.window pero no me redirecciona

Comment: coloca en tu alert(top.window.location) y verifica que el valor coincida con el de tu explorador.

Comment: ya quedo, el inconveniente que tenia es que las cookies del navegador no reconocian los cambios del archivo . js

Answer (score 0):

Ratifica las siguientes cosas:

Solo ratifica que tu else funcione.

Si funciona, entonces verifica cual es la ruta de `cotizacion.php`. Ya que probé tu código y funciona perfecto. Pero hay dos cosas que no estoy y es el contexto. El cual no se la ruta ni tampoco cuando se cumple ese `else`

Comment: si funciona el else  voy a probar con el codigo que me mandaron arriba

Comment: Ratificaste cual es la ruta donde se encuentra cotizacion.php?

Comment: Asi es se enentra en la misma carpeta donde tengo el .js y el arcgivo cotizacion.php

Comment: Entonces desde el archivo que estas llamando esta en la misma carpeta? Eso es correcto?

Comment: Asi es los dos archivos estan en la misma carpeta

Comment: coloca `alert(top.window.location)` y corrobora que sea la misma direccion que la url del explorador

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57499/discussion-between-jose-miguel-sepulveda-and-jose-luis-gp).

Answer (score 0):

Lo ultimo que se me ocurre es que el navegador tiene la cookie o cache con el .js anterior.

Para no seguir teniendo problemas mientras estas desarrollando. Puedes probar vaciando esto en primera instancia, y luego desde la ventana de desarrollador (F12) en la siguiente parte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Activando dicha casilla no te guardará la cache y podrás trabajar con el dato que realmente llamas y no el que esta alojado por el lado del cliente.

Espero ayudarte con ello.

Saludos!!